# Add colon at the end of the text or right aligned depending on the value of RowSpan of a textblock

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a textblock as mentioned in code below:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row=........
           .................
           Grid.RowSpan="{Binding RowSp}"
           HorizontalAlignment="Left" />
```

Now I want to check if `RowSpan > 1`  then I want to add a space and a Colon at the end of the text.**I think**(not tried) I have got it using Triggers and Converter as mentioned in Code below:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="{Binding RowSp, 
                                Converter={StaticResource colonAlignmentConverter}}" 
                     Value="True" >
                <Setter Property="Text" 
                        Value="{Binding Txt, 
                                Converter=ColonAlignmentConverter}" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>

public class ColonAlignmentConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return (int)value > 1;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is here:

If `RowSpan = 1` then I want to add colon(:) in the same Grid.Row and Grid.Column but I want it `right aligned`. How can I achieve this?

I can use another textblock for colon if it is possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would usually be done with templates but, as you already know, you cannot template a TextBlock.

However, when you pass a string to the Content property of a ContentControl, the ContentControl uses a TextBlock to display the string. This was discovered by using [Snoop](http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), an awesome WPF debugging tool.

Taking this into account, the fact that Grid.RowSpan for any child of a Grid has a default value of 1, and that you want to display a colon whenever the TextBlock has a RowSpan greater than 1, the following will do what you want.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow._20820850.MainWindow" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
    <Style x:Key="TextBlockContentControlStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Grid>
                        <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        <TextBlock Text=":" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Grid.RowSpan" Value="1">
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Grid>
                                <TextBlock Text="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                            </Grid>
                        </ControlTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Content="One" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockContentControlStyle}" />
    <ContentControl Content="Two" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" Style="{StaticResource TextBlockContentControlStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Things to note

1. I have replaced the TextBlock with a ContentControl (I am not sure if this option is available to you)
2. I wanted to use a pure XAML approach so my default template is the template that manages RowSpan > 1. I then supply a trigger to set the template back to the default RowSpan = 1.
3. This needs to be a keyed style as setting this as a default style will probably break every other control that utilises the ContentControl in its Logical or Visual tree.

If you do not want to use a ContentControl, another approach would be to create your own UserControl. In the following, I have created a control called MyTextBlock (I could have called it TextBlock and let the namespacing sort it out but this is clearer in an example) and I then Templated the content of the Control. The XAML of the user control is

```
<UserControl x:Name="ThisControl" x:Class="StackOverflow._20820850.MyTextBlock" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"  xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">
    <UserControl.ContentTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid DataContext="{Binding ElementName=ThisControl}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Content}" />
                <TextBlock Text=":" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                    <TextBlock.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type TextBlock}}">
                            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding (Grid.RowSpan)}" Value="1">
                                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                                </DataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </TextBlock.Style>
                </TextBlock>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </UserControl.ContentTemplate>
</UserControl>
```

And the grid in the Window now looks like

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <this:MyTextBlock Content="One" />
    <this:MyTextBlock Content="Two" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2" />
</Grid>
```

Obviously, the colon can be missed as it is pushed right up against the right hand side of the control but I will leave formatting to you.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you. It works as expected. I have followed your first approach of using ContentControl as I dont use ContentControl in my application. I have made some changes to the style you created and added it to application resources. Now it works fine without any approach. Thanks once again.

Comment: Awesome. I am glad it worked out. I would still key the ContentControl as controls can internally use the ContentControl and your styling, unless keyed, will be applied to those as well.